# Regression coefficients displayed as equations

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas

I have generated a csv file with 4 lines corresponding to the coefficients of 2 lines in a chart like this:

```
df=df[["AC_GRADE","ALPHA"]]
df=df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
df.rename(index=str, columns={"AC_GRADE":"Access grade public","ALPHA":"Alpha_public"},inplace=True)
x=list(df[(df.columns[0])])
y=list(df[(df.columns[1])])
parameters_pub = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
df['Regression_public'] = parameters_pub[0] * df[df.columns[0]] + parameters_pub[1]
df=df.round(decimals=2)

df_pp=df_pp[["AC_GRADE","ALPHA"]]
df_pp=df_pp.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
df_pp.rename(index=str, columns={"AC_GRADE":"Access grade private","ALPHA":"Alpha_private"},inplace=True)
x=list(df_pp[(df_pp.columns[0])])
y=list(df_pp[(df_pp.columns[1])])
parameters_pri = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
df_pp['Regression_private'] = parameters_pri[0] * df_pp[df_pp.columns[0]] + parameters_pri[1]
df_pp=df_pp.round(decimals=2)

df_total=pd.concat([df,df_pp],axis=1)
df_total=df_total[["Access grade public","Alpha_public","Access grade private","Alpha_private",'Regression_public','Regression_private']]
df_total=df_total.round(decimals=2)
parameters=np.concatenate((parameters_pub,parameters_pri), axis=0)
np.savetxt("/home/mtintore/mysite/app/static/CSV/Chart_data/parameters.csv", parameters, delimiter=",")
df_total.to_csv("/home/mtintore/mysite/app/static/CSV/Chart_data/alpha_access_pp.csv", index=False)
```

parameters.csv appears well saved like the following:

```
1.150517617398622156e-01
-5.234557848372338729e-01
1.275258227834331071e-01
-6.895679012729082347e-01
```

Now I want to show the equation of the line adding this snippet to the javascript that plots the chart (alpha_access_pp.js):

```
d3.csv('../static/CSV/Chart_data/parameters.csv?rnd='+(new Date).getTime(),function(data){

    var f1 = data[0];
    var f2 = data[1];

    var a = f1[0];
    var b = f2[0];

    a = (Math.round(a*1000)/1000);
    b = (Math.round(b*1000)/1000);
    document.getElementById("equation9").innerHTML = "Public high schools: Alpha = " + a + "·Access grade + " + b;

    var f3 = data[2];
    var f4 = data[3];

    var d = f3[0];
    var c = f4[0];

    d = (Math.round(d*1000)/1000);
    c = (Math.round(c*1000)/1000);
    document.getElementById("equation10").innerHTML = "Private high schools: Alpha = " + c + "·Access grade + " + d;
  })
```

In the html, this is how I call both the javascript containing the chart+the equation display and the ids:

```
<div id="alpha_access_pp"></div>
                                    <div style="line-height:57%;"><br></div>
                                    <p class="w3-container" style="margin: 0 05%" align="justify">The scatter plot compares the α and the access grade of the students and linearly approximates this relationship. The equations of the line's regressions can be used as prediction's of a students' performance once the access grade is known.
                                    The lines that best approximate the expected alpha parameters (α) according to the access grade to University and comparing students from both public and private high schools are:</p>
                                    <div style="line-height:57%;"><br></div>
                                    <div class="w3-center" id="equation9"></div>
                                    <div style="line-height:57%;"><br></div>
                                    <div class="w3-center" id="equation10"></div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/scripts/alpha_access_pp.js"></script>
```

But I see "NaNs" instead of the coefficients of the equations. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: That error generally mean you try do some math on a variable that is not of type `number`. It can be a string that holds a number character though, but then doing math with it will cause a `NaN`. Check the console to see where you get this error.

Comment: @LGSon I think I get the NaNs because it does not find the proper number, that is why I asked for help, to see if you could help me get the parameters of parameters.csv

Comment: Am not familiar with the used libraries, so just wanted to give a hint. Someone who is will likely pass by with a better answer.

Comment: Any idea? @AdityaK